# Determine whether $x^3$ is $O(g(x))$ for certain functions $g(x)$.

Tags: computational-complexity

a) $g(x) = x^2$

b) $g(x) = x^3$

c) $g(x) = x^2 + x^3$

d) $g(x) = x^2 + x^4$

e) $g(x) = 3^x$

f) $g(x) = (x^3)/2$

Do you guys have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: all possible except a..

Comment: $x\to \infty$ ?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show your attempts before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked in a comment about (e), let's discuss that.

Saying "$x^3$ is $O\bigl(3^x\bigr)$" means the following:

> There is some constant $c$, such that for all sufficiently large $x$, $$x^3 < c\cdot3^x.$$

Consider the functions $x^3$ and $3^x$.  Clearly, $3^x$ increases much faster than $x^3$.  For $x=10$, $3^x$ is already 59,049 and $x^3$ is only 1,000.  And $3^x$ triples every time $x$ becomes  $x+1$, whereas $x^3$ does not triple so easily; to triple $x^3$ you have to multiply $x$ by something.

So there is no trouble finding the constant $c$ that we want; $c=1$ will do.  And indeed, for all $x>10$, it is the case that $x^3 < 1\cdot 3^x$.  So $x^3$ is $ O\bigl(3^x\bigr)$.

Now on the other hand, $x^3$ is *not* $O\bigl(x^2\bigr)$.  Why not?  Well, if it were, then

> There is some constant $c$, such that for all sufficiently large $x$, $$x^3 < c\cdot x^2$$

But clearly that's not true, since no matter what $c$ is, $x^3 > c\cdot x^2$ whenever $x>c$.  So $x^3$ is *not* $O\bigl(x^2\bigr)$.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

As $x\to\infty $ :

Well , for polynomials you should just look at the term with highest degree.

Positive coefficients are negligible.

And  $a^x$   always dominate polynomials in the long run for $a>1$..

So , for your question :all possible except a...

Comment: how is A different from B?

Comment: Wait..how is e possible?

Comment: Exponentials dominate polynomials if base > 1..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following result

> $$f=O(g) \iff \limsup_{x \to \infty}\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} =c,$$

where $c$ is finite.